# Hibernate composite pattern design

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, hibernate

I'm designing database tables for the hierarchy as shown in the image below. There are no recursive dependencies, and hence fixed levels. Only the presence of Group1 is hindering the design. In the hierarchy, only Item4 and Item5 have parent as Group1, rest all Items have System as its parents.

Request for your feedback & suggestions.

[image]

I've designed tables as follows:

Site Table - SiteId (PK)

System Table - SystemId (PK), SiteId(FK)

Item Table - ItemId(PK), SystemId(FK)

Group Table - GroupId(PK), ItemId(FK)

In the above design, I intend to use transitive property to identify Item4 and Item5 belong to Group1.

Is this design good? or have any suggestions? Also request for query suggestions in Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Item` and `Group` are on the same level and being associated to the same `System`, I would use inheritance to map their relationship:

So you can have an `AbstractItem` base class which is extended by both `Item` and `Group`, but only `Group` has also a `one-to-many` association to an `Item`.

The System many-to-one association can reside in `AbstractItem`. A `JOIN` inheritance model is probably better for your use case than `SINGLE_TABLE`.

Comment: Though it can solve, I feel the inheritance hierarchy not logical, because `Group` is not of type `Item`, right?

Comment: That's why I introduced their base class, which can be named Component for clarity.